# Google is indexing the root domain rather than the language subdirectory where it redirects

Tags: google-search-console, url, internationalization, language, localization

I have a multi language website for my company.

my language routing goes like `example.com/[language]`.  I have 2 languages, and my URLs are `example.com/tr`,`example.com/en`, and `example.com/` redirects to `example.com/en`.

so `example.com/` and `example.com/en` are counted as the same URL, so google chooses to rank `example.com/` and exclude `example.com/en` although `example.com/en` is included in the sitemap and `example.com/` is not.

the problem here is now `example.com/` is not counted as an only `en` URL although it does redirect to the `/en`, so now in the search results `example.com/` (which redirects to `en`) will appear on top disregarding the language of the user.

I could not see an option to exclude the root URL anywhere, and google indexed it although it is not included in the sitemap. How can I overcome this?

Comment: How long has the root URL been redirecting to a language subdomain?  Sometimes it takes Google a few weeks to sort it out.  So if you recently implemented that, you may just need to give it time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`Google Developers' documentation`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions), you can add localized equivalent for each page

so my sitemap went from

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/en</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-03-22T06:34:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/en/products</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-03-22T06:34:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/en/about</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-03-22T06:34:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/tr</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-03-22T06:34:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/tr/urunler</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-03-22T06:34:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/tr/hakkimizda</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-03-22T06:34:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>

</urlset>
```

to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
      xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr"
  href="https://example.com/tr"/>
  <lastmod>2022-04-21T09:09:08+03:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/en/products</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr"
  href="https://example.com/tr/urunler"/>
  <lastmod>2022-04-21T09:09:08+03:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/en/about</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr"
  href="https://example.com/tr/hakkimizda"/>
  <lastmod>2022-04-21T09:09:08+03:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>

</urlset>
```

in the new version please notice that we've added `xmlns:xhtml` tag to the urlset, to be able to process `xhtml:link` tags.

I'm not sure this will work, so I will come back later after the new sitemap has been indexed!

Comment: You should drop the `lastmod` and `priority` fields from your sitemap.  Google says they don't use them very often, so they end up just bloating your sitemap.  See [When should I update lastmod value in the sitemap?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117090/when-should-i-update-lastmod-value-in-the-sitemap/117099#117099)

Comment: Adding hreflang to your sitemap may help. Do you also use hreflang meta tags on your site?